# The missing address space in 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, memory, x86-64

In today x86-64 processors, the usable address space is 48 bits long and is separated into two halves. One is from 00000000`00000000 to 00007fff`ffffffff, another one is from ffff8000`00000000 to ffffffff`ffffffff.

Now I'm writing a program to catch memory access violation. Here is my code.

```
UINT64 *Test1 = (UINT64 *) 0x0000000000000000;
UINT64 Test2;
AddVectoredExceptionHandler(TRUE,(PVECTORED_EXCEPTION_HANDLER)ExceptionHandler);
Test2 = *Test1;
```

`ExceptionHandler` is a [VEH exception handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I can get the address that cannot access in the [ExceptionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)->[ExceptionRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)->ExceptionInformation[1] (The second array element specifies the virtual address of the inaccessible data.([Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))). At this case, it is 0, same as Test1.

If you are trying to access any address between 00007fff`ffffffff and ffff8000`00000000, ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[1] will be -1. This isn't out of my expectation. But the interesting part is, when I putted 0x00007fffffffffff in the Test1, I also got -1. It didn't take my very long to find that from 00007fff`fffffff8 to 00007fff`ffffffff also return -1, which should be legal address in the system.

Can somebody explain this to me please?

Comment: http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=50, found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563297/behind-windows-x64s-44-bit-virtual-memory-address-limit?rq=1